# repository execute method gives an 'not implement' error loopback4

Tags: loopback

want to execute raw query ,tried with execute but its giving

```
500 Error: Not implemented
```

this is the simplest query which is tried to execute

```
this.tblPlayerRepository.execute(select * from tbl_player,{});
```

can anyone help me out how to use or execute raw query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a query, you should use `this.dataSource.connector.execute` instead.

But in your case, it seems, you should use native loopback repository functions instead, like this:

```
this.tblPlayerRepository.find();
```

It will return a promise of entities.

Comment: how do i get datasource should i import datasource into controller

Comment: you must create a datasource like in the doc here : https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/DataSources.html. Then you can import it in your repository for example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I wanted to run any custom query to a datasource.

I tried few options to execute and I found a way to do it.

You can use and this worked for me.

```
this.dataSource.execute("select * from tbl_player", [])
```